# Cursor in PL SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to call a function, and this function returns a cursor. ¿How can I send a cursor as a parameter? I'm trying the following, but It´s not working.
Thanks.

```
DECLARE
  P_NUMBER NUMBER;
  P_TABCURSOR REF CURSOR;    
BEGIN
  P_NUMBER := '80233068';
  P_TABCURSOR := NULL;

P_TABCURSOR:=  PKG_CHANNEL.OBTAIN_CHANNEL (  P_NUMBER => P_NUMBER,
P_TABCURSOR => P_TABCURSOR) ;  
END;
```

I get this error: PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared

Comment: Define "not working".  Are you getting an error?  What error?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i get this error: PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared

Comment: `REF CURSOR` is not a valid type in PL/SQL.  What is the definition of `pkg_channel.obtain_channel`?  My guess is that it returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR` in which case you'd want to define `p_tabcursor` to be of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  The function, however, might be defined to return a strongly typed ref cursor in which case you'd want your local variable to be of that type as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The definition is: `PROCEDURE obtain_channel ( P_NUMBER IN NUMBER, p_tabcursor OUT typeCursor)` ,  I try to declare as: type cursor, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It must be this one:

```
TYPE P_TABCURSOR_TYPE IS REF CURSOR; 
P_TABCURSOR P_TABCURSOR_TYPE;
```

or

```
P_TABCURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
```

which is exactly the same, just shorter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that your syntax is off. 
I think you want sys_refcursor. There might be an object ref_cursor, but ref cursor is 2 variables to pl/sql

https://community.oracle.com/thread/888365

Answer (score 0):

If `pkg_channel.obtain_channel` has the parameter defined as `typeCursor`, then there must be a type defined in the spec of: `pkg_channel.typecursor`. That's what you need to use as the datatype of the variable that will hold that out parameter.

Also, you're calling a procedure, so you wouldn't try to explicitly set the variable value (i.e. using `:=`). And don't declare a variable as a number, and then try to pass a string in! Instead, you'd do something like:

```
declare
  p_number number;
  p_tabcursor pkg_channel.typecursor;    
begin
  p_number := 80233068;
  pkg_channel.obtain_channel (p_number => p_number,
                              p_tabcursor => p_tabcursor);  
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first make a cursur. 
And then a record where you put every value of the curson into.

Have a look here about CURSORS and RECORDS. 
[Click here for link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/declare.php)

Example:

First you need to create a cursor.

```
CURSOR cursorName is
    SELECT id, name 
    FROM Employee;
```

Then you fetch the records from that cursor into a record.

```
OPEN cursorName; 
LOOP 
    FETCH cursorName INTO recordName
    EXIT WHEN cursorName%notfound;
END LOOP
```